# Mysql Efficiency and safety of swapping rows with unique values using user variables as temporary storage

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to swap two rows in mysql using the most efficient method.

My current code is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11),
  `email` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
);

INSERT INTO `user` VALUES 
(1,'john@a.com'),
(2,'fred@b.com');

SET @FROM=2, @TO=1;

SELECT @FROM.email:=email FROM user WHERE id = @FROM;
SELECT @TO.email:=email FROM user WHERE id = @TO;

UPDATE user 
  SET email=NULL
  WHERE id IN (@FROM, @TO);

UPDATE user 
  SET email=@FROM.email
  WHERE id=@TO;

UPDATE user 
  SET email=@TO.email
  WHERE id=@FROM;
```

You can see a SQLFiddle of this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc3af/2).

Is there any way I can optimize this code to have less queries in it, and is it safe to do this (considering that both records are temporarily deleted) when we're dealing with a large table (with 10+ columns/variables) and a slow and possibly unstable connection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1- Use transactions if the table is InnoDB
2- You may want to use a temporary table with the same structure, except the unique constraint, and use it to swap the values, then update the original table.